# associative arrays is not creating while using json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this JSON file:

```
{
"generated":
{
    "timestamp":1432146154000,
    "human":"May 20th 2015,     9:22:34pm",
    "by":{"guid":"a4e60f48-b405-4d7c-a655-395ccc9b639b","username":"kuses129","email":"odeddolev@gmail.com","roles":["USER"],"orgGuid":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}
},
"columns":
[
    {
        "id":"_input","name":"Input","special":true
    },
    {
        "id":"_num","name":"Result Number","special":true
    },
    {
        "id":"_widgetName","name":"Widget","special":true
    },
    {
        "id":"_source","name":"Data Origin","special":true
    },
    {
        "id":"_resultNumber","name":"Result Row","special":true
    },
    {
        "id":"_pageUrl","name":"Source Page URL","special":true
    },
    {
        "id":"image","name":"Image","special":false
    },
    {
        "id":"name","name":"Name","special":false
    },
    {
        "id":"lowest_price","name":"Lowest price","special":false
    },
    {
        "id":"descrition","name":"Descrition","special":false
    }
],
"data":
[
    {
        "descrition":["יצרן: Samsung,   גודל מסך: 5.1‏ אינטש,   מערכת הפעלה: Android,   שנת הכרזה: 2014,   מהירות מעבד: MHz‏ 2500,   זיכרון RAM: MB‏ 2048,   נפח אחסון פנימי: 16GB,   רזולוציה: 1080x1920‏ פיקסלים,   צפיפות פיקסלים: ppi‏ 432,   מצלמה: 16 מגה פיקסל,   עובי: 8.1‏ מ\"מ,   משקל: 145‏ גרם,   קיבולת הסוללה: mAh‏ 2800,"],"lowest_price/_source":["1,988 ₪"],
        "name":["Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F 16GB LTE"],
        "image":["http://img.zap.co.il/pics/new/104201495714b.gif"],
        "lowest_price":[1988],
        "image/_alt":["טלפון סלולרי Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F 16GB LTE"],
        "image/_title":["טלפון סלולרי Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F 16GB LTE"],
        "_resultNumber":1,
        "_widgetName":"cellphones from zap",
        "_source":["7d17a185-b985-4c2f-b55e-69146fba3d29"],
        "_pageUrl":"http://www.zap.co.il/models.aspx?sog=e-cellphone&keyword=galaxy",
        "_outputTypes":{"image":"IMAGE","name":"STRING","lowest_price":"CURRENCY","descrition":"STRING"},
        "_input":{"cellphones":"galaxy"},
        "_num":1
    }
]
}
```

and I try to use to arrays with the string keys that are defined in the file but for some reason my PHP does not recognize them as indexes.
This doesn't work `$jsondata = file_get_contents("cellphones.json");`

```
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo gettype($data["data"]);
echo current($data["data"]["name"]);
```

but this will `$jsondata = file_get_contents("cellphones.json");`

```
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo gettype($data["data"]);
echo current($data["data"][0]);
```

I don't understand why a numeric index works and a string key doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$data['data']['name']` does not exist.  If you dumped the contents of `$data['data']`.  You would see something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [descrition] => Array
            (
                [0] => יצרן: Samsung,   גודל מסך: 5.1‏ אינטש,   מערכת הפעלה: Android,   שנת הכרזה: 2014,   מהירות מעבד: MHz‏ 2500,   זיכרון RAM: MB‏ 2048,   נפח אחסון פנימי: 16GB,   רזולוציה: 1080x1920‏ פיקסלים,   צפיפות פיקסלים: ppi‏ 432,   מצלמה: 16 מגה פיקסל,   עובי: 8.1‏ מ"מ,   משקל: 145‏ גרם,   קיבולת הסוללה: mAh‏ 2800,
            )

        [lowest_price/_source] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1,988 ₪
            )

        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F 16GB LTE
            )

        [image] => Array
            (
                [0] => http://img.zap.co.il/pics/new/104201495714b.gif
            )

        [lowest_price] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1988
            )

        [image/_alt] => Array
            (
                [0] => טלפון סלולרי Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F 16GB LTE
            )

        [image/_title] => Array
            (
                [0] => טלפון סלולרי Samsung Galaxy S5 SM-G900F 16GB LTE
            )

        [_resultNumber] => 1
        [_widgetName] => cellphones from zap
        [_source] => Array
            (
                [0] => 7d17a185-b985-4c2f-b55e-69146fba3d29
            )

        [_pageUrl] => http://www.zap.co.il/models.aspx?sog=e-cellphone&keyword=galaxy
        [_outputTypes] => Array
            (
                [image] => IMAGE
                [name] => STRING
                [lowest_price] => CURRENCY
                [descrition] => STRING
            )

        [_input] => Array
            (
                [cellphones] => galaxy
            )

        [_num] => 1
    )

)
```

So, if you want to get the name property, you would be looking for `$data['data'][0]['name'][0]`

Edit: to answer your question, you could make a function like this

```
function getDataValue($a, $k) {
    return $a['data'][0][$k][0];
}
```

Then you would call it, in your context, it would look like this

```
current(getDataValue($data, 'name'));
```

Comment: is there away to make it the whole thing shorter so it will be something like what i first meant?

Comment: see my edit, this is one option but it wouldn't work if the `$data['data']` array ever had more then one element, and it would need to be more complex to access some of the nested arrays like `_outputTypes`